# How to set PostgreSQL script parameters in DBeaver or PgAdmin?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, dbeaver, postgresql-12

`PostgreSQL v12.6` `DBEaver 7.1.0`

**How to set SQL script parameters in DBeaver or PgAdmin?**
(any working option is welcome)

This script works perfectly when I run it as a script on DB initialization
(i.e. from Docker's `postgres:12.6-alpine` in `/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql`.
No doubts this script is valid for execution through `psql`.

```
\set app_schema  my_schema
\set app_username  my_app
\set app_password  my_app_pwd
 
CREATE SCHEMA :app_schema;
ALTER SCHEMA :app_schema OWNER TO "admin";
CREATE USER :app_username WITH PASSWORD :'app_password';
```

But I cannot find a way to set parameters in DBeaver script. Non of these is valid:

```
\set app_schema  my_schema
set app_schema=my_schema
set :app_schema=my_schema
:app_schema=my_schema
... and many more ...
```

As well did not find any information about doing this in PGAdmin.

Comment: I found @set working. But it has issues with array

Answer (score 0):

Just had this issue. In DBeaver, the default control command prefix is `@`. Under `File > Properties > Editors > SQL Processing > Control command prefix` you can set that to `\` and it should work.

[image]

Just noting however, that there might be a good reason to why Dbeaver set `@` as the default command prefix and there may be unknown implications to changing it to `\`.